# Curl connection pooling in PHP

Tags: php, connection-pooling

Is there a way to pool or reuse HTTP connections with PHP's curl client? I already found [Persistent/keepalive HTTP with the PHP Curl library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972925/persistent-keepalive-http-with-the-php-curl-library), but it only allows connection reuse on the same handle, and there isn't a good way to persist handles between multiple fastcgi PHP calls, and that's probably a bad idea because the handle might never be closed.

The only solution I found was routing the requests through a proxy that does connection pooling.

Comment: Interesting question, can you clarify what you meant by `multiple fastcgi PHP calls` ?

Comment: Sure; and it changes what @lars-stegelitz was answering. What I really meant is that within a php script, is there a way to reuse HTTP connections across script invocations. In this case, it's a web page, so fastcgi (or mod-php) will make the PHP call.

Comment: I see, if I understand you correctly, itsn't this something `curl_multi_*` methods can fix for you?

Comment: @MostafaBerg sadly, no, because there isn't a way to save (or release) handles or multi-handles between calls.

Comment: Of course, I misunderstood you!, I thought method invocations, not script invocations. I'll look around and update if I have any findings, I haven't come across that use case before

Comment: I'm surprised it's not a more common use case. If this were actual `php` command line calls, I get how it'd be unusual, from when it's for a web page, it seems like sharing HTTP connections between Apache/Nginx requests would be a normal thing to do.

Comment: I meant that as in "PHP is stateless", so this use case is not really something natural for PHP, but I'm sure there's a way, but how uncommon it is, makes it kind of scary to go down that path, I'll still be researching though :)

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Have you found the solution? I've faced the similar problem and the only solution right now is using local proxy that keeps connections opened. Thanks!

Comment: @Kirzilla Nope; I did exactly that, use Apache/Nginx/whatever as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the Webserver and the fast-CGI configuration.

Should be possible with fast-CGI, but the webserver has to support it as well.

Read this SO article, which has a good explanation what multiplexing can do for you

[fastcgi multiplexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912322/fastcgi-multiplexing)