# What is the meaning of "multiplexing" in FastCGI?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, multiplexing

Appendix B of the [FastCGI specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306081510/http://fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/22#SB) gives an example of multiplexing, where the unindented lines are the sent by the client (e.g. Nginx), and the indented lines are sent by the FastCGI server:

```
{FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,   1, {FCGI_RESPONDER, FCGI_KEEP_CONN}}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          1, "\013\002SERVER_PORT80\013\016SERVER_ADDR199.170.183.42 ... "}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          1, ""}
{FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,   2, {FCGI_RESPONDER, FCGI_KEEP_CONN}}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          2, "\013\002SERVER_PORT80\013\016SERVER_ADDR199.170.183.42 ... "}
{FCGI_STDIN,           1, ""}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      1, "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          2, ""}
{FCGI_STDIN,           2, ""}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      2, "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html>\n<head> ... "}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      2, ""}
    {FCGI_END_REQUEST, 2, {0, FCGI_REQUEST_COMPLETE}}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      1, "<html>\n<head> ... "}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      1, ""}
    {FCGI_END_REQUEST, 1, {0, FCGI_REQUEST_COMPLETE}}
```

From my understanding, in a non-multiplexed version of the above, the FastCGI client (e.g. Nginx) will send request 1 before sending anything to do with request 2:

(Figure 2):

```
{FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,   1, {FCGI_RESPONDER, FCGI_KEEP_CONN}}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          1, "\013\002SERVER_PORT80\013\016SERVER_ADDR199.170.183.42 ... "}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          1, ""}
{FCGI_STDIN,           1, ""}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      1, "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      1, "<html>\n<head> ... "}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      1, ""}
    {FCGI_END_REQUEST, 1, {0, FCGI_REQUEST_COMPLETE}}
{FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,   2, {FCGI_RESPONDER, FCGI_KEEP_CONN}}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          2, "\013\002SERVER_PORT80\013\016SERVER_ADDR199.170.183.42 ... "}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          2, ""}
{FCGI_STDIN,           2, ""}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      2, "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html>\n<head> ... "}
    {FCGI_STDOUT,      2, ""}
    {FCGI_END_REQUEST, 2, {0, FCGI_REQUEST_COMPLETE}}
```

Is my understanding correct?

I read in a few places that Nginx does not support multiplexing for FastCGI:

- [fastcgi multiplexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912322/fastcgi-multiplexing)
- [Why Nginx Doesn't Implement FastCGI Multiplexing?](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,237158,237158)

However, that appears to be contradicted by [multi threaded FastCGI App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829869/multi-threaded-fastcgi-app), where it is mentioned that Nginx does not wait for a response from the first request before sending the second request, like this:

(Figure 3):

```
{FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,   1, {FCGI_RESPONDER, FCGI_KEEP_CONN}}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          1, "\013\002SERVER_PORT80\013\016SERVER_ADDR199.170.183.42 ... "}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          1, ""}
{FCGI_STDIN,           1, ""}
{FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,   2, {FCGI_RESPONDER, FCGI_KEEP_CONN}}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          2, "\013\002SERVER_PORT80\013\016SERVER_ADDR199.170.183.42 ... "}
{FCGI_PARAMS,          2, ""}
{FCGI_STDIN,           2, ""}
```

I am confused at this point, because from my understanding, a non-multiplexed version should only handle one request at a time (i.e. receive the request, and send a response for that request before handling the next request). What exactly is the meaning of multiplexing? In particular:

- Does non-multiplexing allow new requests to be accepted before a response is given for an old request? (e.g. referring to the snippet below, see the acceptance of request B before response A is given).

  (Figure 4):

  ```
  {Request A}
  {Request B}
       {Response A}
  {Request C}
       {Response C}
       {Response B}
  ```
- Does non-multiplexing allow responses to be given in a different order from the requests? (e.g. request order: A, B, C; response order: A, C, B).
- Does multiplexing mean that parts of a request can be intermingled with parts of other requests and responses? e.g.

  (Figure 5):

  ```
  {Small part of request A}
  {Small part of request B}
  {Small part of request A}
  {Small part of request B}
       {Small part of response A}
  {Small part of request B}
       {Small part of response B}
  ...
  ```

Note that I am new to networking and FastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

Without multiplexing, nginx simply makes a new *connection* to the fastcgi listen socket when it gets a new request. Multiple requests are handled in parallel, in whatever order, but each connection only carries data for one request at a time. This is exactly the same way things are done with HTTP/1, and with many other protocols.

Comment: So multiplexing = a connection between nginx and FastCGI handles multiple requests. No multiplexing = nginx makes a new connection to FastCGI for every request. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Flux not necessarily. A connection can handle more than one request *in sequence* without multiplexing, but not more than one request *in parallel*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So figures 2 and 3 are possible without multiplexing, and figure 5 is only possible with multiplexing. What about figure 4? Can the responses be given is a different order than the requests?